# Loading Grub2 from a different location?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot

Before I explain my issue, let me start by saying that I am relatively new with Ubuntu so please be patient with me !

I had a Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot system, and everything was running smoothly.

A week or so ago, I decided to install 13.04 alongside of W7 and 12.04, and since then, I think I am now using Grub from a different location.

When I only had 12.04 (prior installing 13.04), I had used Grub Customizer to add some colour and change the background of my Grub boot menu.

The Grub2 menu that now I see when I boot does not have this customisation.

However, when I do boot 12.04 and run Grub Customizer, I do see the colours/background that I used to see/have when I only had 12.04.

s there any way to tell Ubuntu to use the Grub files that I had customized ?

(Ubuntu 12.04 is on SD5, and 13.04 is on SD8)

Thank you very much in advance !!!

Dan

Comment: You mean, Ubuntu 12.04 is installed on a different drive and Ubuntu 13.04 is installed on a different drive?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed 13.04, it reinstalled the Grub bootloader to the drive MBR and this is pointing at the 13.04 install, not the 12.04 install. You can still boot the 12.04 install, but it won't be the first one in the list.

Therefore all your customizations in the 12.04 install are not taken into account. You can fix this by booting your 12.04 install, and reinstalling grub:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will put 12.04 back in charge of booting as it were (the Grub bootloader will be loading modules and the configuration from 12.04) and you'll see the 12.04 install at the top of the Grub menu again.